# Image Editing Issue

Tags: iphone, ios

I am working on an app with have requirement to give "Droste Effects" on image.i did search on Google more but not find programming solution for this effects.the effect example in there below.

http://apping.me/ios/4eb514ba8491783f5b0001e2/droste+vision.html

http://www.pmavridis.com/iDroste/iDroste.html

Please provide me suggestion or any tutorials link. How i will do that task?.Thanks in advance.

Comment: As a hint: watch the WWDC 2010 session "Core Image Effects and Optimization" and dig into the custom Core Image kernel code here: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/Droste/Introduction/Intro.html . The translation of this to iOS is up to you.

Answer (score 3):

The Droste effect is a trick made with some intense mathematics and a recursive function. Please read http://www.josleys.com/article_show.php?id=82. If you don't know about recursion please read up http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion. Since your request is very specific I doubt there will be many people who happen to have a Droste effect code written in the iphone programming langauge, but the links above should help you understand the math behind creating your own. Good luck.